# Estimating volume of the solid using MidPoint Rule

Tags: calculus, integration

[image: figure]

> If the region shown in the figure is rotated about the $x$-axis to form a solid, use Midpoint rule with $n=4$ to estimate the volume of the solid.

I am not sure what this question is asking me to do. I believe at $x=3,\,5,\,7$, and $9$ the figure will be rotated around the $x$-axis. Is it the average of the volume of these points that will be the answer?

Comment: Does it want you to do trapeziums (so you’ll get cone frustums) or rectangles (so you’ll get cylinders)?

Comment: @AdamRubinson I believe cylinders

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you familiar with the disk method for determining the volume of solids of revolution?  You are being asked to approximate that integral with four disks, each one having a radius of the midpoint of its thickness, which you have correctly determined are $3,5,7,9$.  So compute the volume of the four disks and add them up.

Comment: I think I understand what you mean, but I did not get the correct answer. What I did was add 4 definite integrals (2-4, 4-6, 6-8, 8-10) of pi * the (y value of the midpoint)^2 * dx.

Comment: The value of $y$ at the midpoint is the radius of the disk and the height is $2$, so you should just add $2 \pi y^2$ for each of the four disks.  You are doing the integral this way, so there should not be an integral inside.

Comment: Thanks. That was the correct method

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

Compute square of $y$ values by approximating midpoints and arrive at all the trapeziums. Next use Simpson's Rule as if finding areas.